# Using Google maps in Android Studio - Mapfragment is blank

Tags: android, google-maps

I've recently updated to the new version of Android.  Since the update, I've been having issues getting my map to appear.  I just regenerated the API key multiple times to no avail

**Here is my manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.morticia.android.pop">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
-->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />

<permission
    android:name="com.VertexVerveInc.GPSLocator.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<!-- <permission -->
<!-- android:name="com.google.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" -->
<!-- android:protectionLevel="signature" > -->
<!-- </permission> -->

<uses-permission android:name="com.VertexVerveInc.GPSLocator.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/usericonldpi"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB94l1WasdFKus_ymBzhqHz1e3WVY5AUig" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:exported="true" />

    </activity>
</application>
```

**Here is my gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.morticia.android.pop"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

ext{
    supportLibVersion = '25.3.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '25.3.0'
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Here is the activity onCreate():**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, OnClickListener{
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
//    CircleSize circSize;

LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser user;

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private PopCityCollection cities;
CityReferrenceDAO cityRef;

private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map_activity);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
    SlidingUpPanelLayout spl = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    FriendsActivity friends = new FriendsActivity();
    viewPager.setAdapter(new FriendFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), friends));
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    //check for pops method needs to be added (include pop just made)



}
```

**Edit: Here is my xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">


    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="50dp"
        sothree:paddingEnd="16dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
        sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
        sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
        sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/list">

        <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            map:id="@+id/map_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.morticia.android.pop.MapsActivity" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.morticia.android.pop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                android:background="@color/colorSalmon"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: try to update you google play services , i had the same problem once so i updated google play services of my phone and it worked

Comment: post your XML code related to map fragment

Comment: @AdeelTurk thank you for the response.  It appears to be up to date in SDK manager.  the issue persists.

Comment: you are welcome @TJBlack31 i just shared my experience

Comment: @TJBlack31 if your app support API level 11 or above than you should use MapFragment instead SupportMapFragment and change XML accordingly

Comment: @AdeelJaved  Updated with the xml.  Currently using a map fragment

Comment: @AdeelJaved xml has been added

Comment: @TJBlack31 In XML, your attributes should use same prefix like you are using map prefix for id and "android" prefix for other attributes

<fragment android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:id="@+id/map_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: @AdeelJaved fixed.  They are all prefixed properly now.  Thanks!

Comment: @AdeelJaved That didn't fix it, but the prefixes were wrong

Comment: @AdeelJaved This issue has been resolved.  It was something I overlooked post Android update. Check out the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

This issue wasn't due to a blank map, but the camera was simply zoomed into the ocean.  My style JSON has water color as being different than normal.  The issue was caused after updating Android and Location was not enabled by default. The solution was manually enabling Location on the device on the device's settings so that the camera could programmatically adjust based on location.

Thanks!

-TJBlack31